# Sublime Text 3 "plugin_host" has exited unexpectedly

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Whenever I try to open any file in sublime text by doubling clicking the plugin_host crashes and there is also an error of syntax file for Plain text unable to open. However when I Right-Click and select "Open with Sublime text" it opens up normally.
Here is the console log:

```
DPI scale: 1.25
startup, version: 3103 windows x64 channel: stable
executable: /C/Program Files (x86)/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /D/abc
packages path: /C/Users/Vedant Kashyap/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /C/Users/Vedant Kashyap/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /C/Program Files (x86)/Sublime Text 3/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/Vedant Kashyap/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Vintage"]
generating syntax summary
generating meta info summary
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/folder.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/spinner7.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/spinner6.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/spinner5.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/spinner4.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/spinner3.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/spinner2.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/spinner1.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/spinner.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/icons/folder_dup.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/panels.png
pre session restore time: 0.438523
startup time: 0.722523
first paint time: 0.725523
error: Error loading syntax file "Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage": Unable to open Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/arrow_left.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/arrow_right.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/arrow_down.png
Unable to decode Packages/Theme - Default/fold.png
unable to launch plugin_host
error: plugin_host has exited unexpectedly, plugin functionality won't be available until Sublime Text has been restarted
```

Yes I have installed a Numix theme however the problem doesn't get solved when I remove that theme. I've tried reinstalling sublime text but the problem didn't get fixed.
 So do I have to solve this the hard way by removing plugins one by one and testing whether the problem is fixed or not or is there some other solution?

Comment: No idea if it will solve the problem or not but try installing the latest version, which is Build 3126. Your version, 3103, is 10 months old.

Comment: maybe you have Comodo installed? https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-windows-10-plugin-host-has-exited-unexpectedly/24443/4

Comment: @KeithHall No I haven't Installed comodo.

Comment: FWIW, my answer to your deleted question, which I don't think was a duplicate: http://pastie.org/10977861

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder ... well people marked it as a duplicate so I pretty much deleted the question thinking it would be of no use... so I guess I will put the post question again. Thanks for the help as well :)